# pitfalls in renaming files in bash

Tags: bash, posix, renaming

I am reading a guide here
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030
on this link a few examples are given I am trying to understand them one example code says

```
# Bash
# Replace all spaces with underscores
for f in *\ *; do mv -- "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

what I have known till now was use of a backslash for special characters like space of ~ or # etc in case of search and replace 
examples or in shell scripts here in above example they have
used  `${f// /_}`
forward slashes , I am not clear with this is this allowed?
in another example on same page
they give an example to remove space and replace it with underscores

`find . -depth -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'dir=${1%/*} base=${1##*/};

 mv "$1" "$dir/${base// /_}"' _ {} \;`

in above example I am not clear with following
1) `dir=${1%/*}`
2) `base=${1##*/}`
3) and when it says `mv "$1"` what is meant by $1 in the above statement,
4) finally the find command is being closed with `-exec <something> _ {} \;`
now what is the use of an underscore _ ,curly braces  {} and a backslash followed by a colon above \;?
in the third example they say

```
# tolower - convert file names to lower case
# POSIX
for file in "$@"do 
   [ -f "$file" ] || continue                # ignore non-existing names   
 newname=$(echo "$file" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')     # lower case   
 [ "$file" = "$newname" ] && continue      # nothing to do   
 [ -f "$newname" ] && continue             # don't overwrite existing files  
  mv -- "$file" "$newname"done
```

I am not clear with following lines
5) `[ -f "$file" ] || continue # ignore non-existing names`
I am not clear with [ ] tests the condition if $file exists then what is the use of OR condition || here and the continue statement
6) `[ -f "$newname" ] && continue # don't overwrite existing files` same doubt here as in point 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${f// /_}
```

means: replace all occurences of spaces with underscores

[`ref`](http://thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation)

---

```
${1%/*}
```

means: remove shortest match of `/*` from end of string

[`ref`](http://thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation)

---

```
${1##*/}
```

means: remove longest match of `*/` from front of string

[`ref`](http://thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation)

---

> when it says `mv "$1"` what is meant by $1

`$1` is the first positional parameter. So if your script has this

```
echo $1
```

and you call like this

```
foo.sh 111
```

then output will be

```
111
```

---

> finally the find command is being closed with `-exec <something> _ {} \;`
>   now what is the use of an underscore `_` , curly braces `{}` and a backslash
>   followed by a colon above `\;`?

The underscore is a placeholder for parameter `$0`

[`ref`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

The `{} \;` idiom is used with `find`, to say: run this command once for each file

[`ref`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

---

```
[ -f "$file" ] || continue
```

means: if `$file` is not a FILE, then continue (immediately end the current iteration of the loop and start the next)

[`ref`](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html)

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, about the substitution, you have, from `man bash`:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>
> ```
>  Pattern substitution. ... If pattern begins with /, all matches
> of  pattern  are replaced   with  string.   Normally  only
> the  first  match  is replaced.
> ```

Which means that, `${parameter/pattern/string}` replaces the first occurrence of `pattern` in `parameter` by `string`, where `${parameter//pattern/string}` replaces all of the matchings.

For the second section:

1. `dir=${1%/*}`

   `$1` is the first argument of a script, and may be accessed via itsequivalent `${1}`, which allows parameter expansions, such as `%...`, that deletes the shortest  matching  pattern in `${1}`, considering the pattern as `/*`;
2. `base=${1##*/}`

   this deletes the longest matching prefix `##`, considering the pattern `*/`; this means that, in `x="a/b/c/d"`, `${x##*/}` will give you `d`;
3. as pointed before, `$1` is the first argument of your script;
4. the backslash followed by a colon is purely syntax, required to cause `-exec ...` to stop parsing the command line -- to point the end of the command;
5. that's, somehow, quite self contained: you have the condition, an `or` operator, and the second part of the operator, which may be read, in a whole, as

   > if $file exists, go to the next line, or/otherwise, continue (skip the current iteration of the for loop);
6. as well as you pointed, the case is quite the same, except for the operator, that causes the interpretation, this one time, to be:

   > if a file named $newname already exists, skip to the next iteration;

   another way to read it is

   > a file named $newname exists AND skips to the next iteration.

You can get more information in the initial questions, concerning parameter expansions, from `man bash | less -p "Parameter Expansion"`.